# column sum based on row length

Tags: r

I would like to calculate column sum based on a given row length. For example, I have 3 row [(day, 1: 181), GDD, Temp]). I am trying to calculate GDD sum if the row length is 1: 104, for instance. In another case, row length is 1: 82.

Example:

```
Day GDD Temp
1   19.77   20.31
2   18.4    19.12
3   16.91   17.7
4   16.46   17.24
5   16.88   17.57
6   18.58   19.25
7   17.31   17.89
8   16.56   17.19
9   15.5    16.15
10  15.78   16.58
.   .   .
.   .   .
.   .   .
.   .   .
```

could someone help me to calculate column sums. I need to do it for 1000 different row lengths.
thanks in advance,
RV

Comment: Not clear what you asking here. Are you just trying to calculate `sum(df[1:104, "GDD])`? (assuming df is your data set)

Comment: @user4039482 You can create a function using David Arenburg's code and apply accordingly.  `fun1 <- function(data, rowind, Col){
 sum(data[rowind, Col], na.rm=TRUE)
 };  fun1(df, 1:5, "GDD")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try for `multiple` row lengths

```
  fun1 <- function(data, rowind, Col){
             sum(data[rowind, Col], na.rm=TRUE) #@David Arenburg's suggestion
              }

  set.seed(42)
  dat1 <- data.frame(Day=1:1000, GDD=rnorm(1000,20,5), Temp= rnorm(1000,22,8))
```

Create a list with different row lengths, for example:

```
  lst1 <- list(1:10, 1:50, 5:25, 3:80)
  sapply(lst1, function(x) fun1(dat1, x, "GDD"))
  #[1]  227.3648  991.0821  434.4308 1564.0305
```